# Spring data rest test params for invalid chars

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

In a simple java jpa spring data rest service where we hava a POJO plus jpa crud interface, is there a way to check for invalid chars in the request string.

for example:

http://www.myjavaDataRestApi/findById?id=1234  .... is good

http://www.myjavaDataRestApi/findByIf?id=%zzz@@1234 .... I want to intercept this and remove the bad char before going to DB.

In the simple Person example I am using.   I have a Person Entity annotated with @Entity ; @Table ; @Column and a corresponding JPA repo interface. I have no controller @RequestMapping in this experiment.

if you are aware of how to do this without standing up a controller, please advise.

Many Thanks

Comment: You can add a Filter to check request params

Comment: Hello ... Thank you for the reply.  I would appreciate an example if possible ... here is my interface ..   Page findByNameIn(@Param("names") Collection<String> names, Pageable pageable);
    
    and I call it :   findByNameIn?names=mark,Jim,##$$Jimmy$$$,Sue??         how would a replace the special chars with "" except for the comma?   In a body of a function I would do this with regex.   I can't figure out how to add regex here.   Thank you for the help